# how to read value for Complex Text-Only Elements using XMLBean

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xmlbeans

I have created a Complex Text-Only element as:-

```
<xs:element name="trackingidtag" type="tagtype"/>
<xs:complexType name="tagtype">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute ref="parenttag" use="required"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

My XML has the element as:-

```
<trackingidtag parenttag="ParentTag">TagValue</trackingidtag>
```

Now I am trying to read the value for this element using XMLBean generated API, but when I do

```
getTrackingidtag()
```

It doesn't give me any method to read the value "TagValue". I have a method for reading the parenttag attribute but nothing for reading the text value.
How can I read "TagValue"?